# anonymous union and nested struct conversion to c#

Tags: c#, struct, unions

I am trying to create the structure below in C# so I can communicate with my Lumenera CCD. The code below is taken from the c++ header file. The main problem is the anonymous union and nested struct part. Any help you be greatly appreciated. An equivalent example would be awesome.

```
typedef struct {
        FLOAT exposure;        
        FLOAT gain;            
        union {
         struct {
          FLOAT gainRed;     
          FLOAT gainBlue;     
          FLOAT gainGrn1;     
          FLOAT gainGrn2;     
         };
         struct {
          FLOAT gainMag;     
          FLOAT gainCyan;     
          FLOAT gainYel1;     
          FLOAT gainYel2;    
         };
        };
      union
      {
           BOOL useStrobe;        
         ULONG strobeFlags;   
      };

} LUCAM_SNAPSHOT;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)] 
public struct LUCAM_SNAPSHOT
{
    [FieldOffset(0)] public float exposure;
    [FieldOffset(4)] public float gain;
    [FieldOffset(8)] public float gainRed;
    [FieldOffset(8)] public float gainGrn1;
    [FieldOffset(8)] public float gainGrn2;
    [FieldOffset(12)] public float gainMag;
    [FieldOffset(12)] public float gainGrn1;
    [FieldOffset(12)] public float gainGrn2;
    [FieldOffset(12)] public float gainMag;
    [FieldOffset(16)] public byte useStrobe;
    [FieldOffset(16)] public int strobeFlags;
}
```

I think it might be something like the above. I have not tried it out, but at least you have a starting point.

Comment: Not really, you got it the other way around.. gainRed need to occupy the same memory of gainMag. But yes, it is a starting point ;)

Comment: Many thanks TYY for you quick reply. You made my day as I have finally understood how the conversion is done. Could not get it work on LUCAM_SNAPSHOT struct yet however it did work on a different struct that is part of the LUCAM_SNAPSHOT struct (not shown here).

Comment: Thank you dema80 for your input, you are correct it was the other way around. As soon as I get it working will publish the full struct so anyone having similar issues with  Lumenera CCD can get it working strait away.